# Работа с Drag and Drop на Андроид.

Tags: android, java, drag-n-drop

Всем добрый день.
В процессе проектирования приложения встала необходимость реализации View которое можно было бы перемещать по экрану моего приложения поверх других элементов управления, в частности имеется ListView на весь экран, а поверх него должна быть моя кнопочка которую я смогу перемешать в любое место поверх данной активности.

Как я понимаю для реализации данной функции нужно использовать Drag and Drop, но пока ничего толкового у меня не получается. Чтобы понять, что я имею ввиду приложил ниже скрин того как это должно выглядеть.

Буду рад любой помощи!

Заранее большое всем спасибо!

[image]

**UPD 1:**

**UPD 2**

Реализовал функционал перетаскивания элемента поверх других, но теперь встал вопрос как ограничить поле перемещения вьюшки, то есть чтобы при перемещении она не выходила за рамки экрана, а еще круче отскакивала от них.

Также теперь не могу привязать кликабельность данной вьюшке, то есть если задействовал onTouchListener, то onClick не работает.

Может кто подскажет, а то сам уже не въезжаю!

Вот [ссылка](http://zalil.ru/34760295) на исходники проекта.

Ниже код:

```
public class dnd extends Activity
```

{

```
private static final String IMAGE_ITEM = "image";
private static final String SUB_ITEM = "sub_item";
private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myList;

String names = "hello";
int images = R.drawable.icon;
public FrameLayout board;
public View pawn;
public Button but;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    board = new FrameLayout(this);
    pawn = new View(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    createList(list, getBaseContext());

    board = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.Board);
    pawn = findViewById(R.id.Pawn);
    pawn.setOnTouchListener(dragt);
    but = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    but.setOnTouchListener(dragt);

}


public void basket(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "hello my click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("hello");    
}

public void createList(ListView list, final Context context) {
    myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> hashmap;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        hashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hashmap.put(IMAGE_ITEM, images);
        hashmap.put(SUB_ITEM, names);
        myList.add(hashmap);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, myList,
            R.layout.list_but, new String[] { IMAGE_ITEM, SUB_ITEM },
            new int[] { R.id.imageView1, R.id.textView1 });
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

OnTouchListener dragt = new OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button1:
            {
                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    {
                        par.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                        par.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                        par.bottomMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                        par.rightMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                        v.setLayoutParams(par);
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    {
                        par.height = 40;
                        par.width = 40;
                        par.topMargin = (int)event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
                        par.leftMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                        par.bottomMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                        par.rightMargin = (int)event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth()/2);
                        v.setLayoutParams(par);
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    {
                        par.height = 60;
                        par.width = 60;
                        v.setLayoutParams(par);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{ 
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.quit:
        {
            Toast.makeText(dnd.this, "Bye!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dnd.this.finish();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [вот этот пример](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2012/07/drag-and-drop-android.html). Тут есть ограничение на перемещение вьюшки, и вроде бы нет проблем с наложением.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](http://www.mobilab.ru/androiddev/drag-and-drop-in-android.html) немного написано про применение Drug and Drop в Android. Может будет полезно Вам.

Comment: Читал эту статью и еще с 10 других, но ничего если честно не получилось! Вопрос как сделать ее поверх ListView и при этом добавить возможность перетаскивания ее по экрану.

Comment: Если честно, пока не особо разбираюсь в Android...
Вы через движок делаете? Вроде бы в AndEngine можно делать несколько слоев на одной сцене? Не копали в этом направлении?

Comment: Нет я пользуюсь только стандартными средствами из Android SDK. Если Вы видели оффициальное приложение Facebook для iOS, то там Вы в действии сможете увидеть данную примочку в разделе активных диалогов.

Comment: Не могу понять как задать свойство элемента так чтобы он всегда был поверх других, и при касании в облать экрана где находится несколько элементов, максимальный приоритет при касании был у моего?