# Можно ли установить ClickListener на края экрана?

Tags: java, android

Есть несколько экранов, оформлено с помощью flipper, переключаюсь по кнопкам (влево,вправо).

Все экраны содержат разные компоненты.

Надо сделать переключение по краям экрана. Например как вызов Navigation Drawer.

Можно ли это сделать и как?

Comment: имеется ввиду, до упора подвинуть мышь до края экрана, и по щелчку будет переключение?

Comment: >>мышь до края экрана<< ключевой тег "android", намекает что скорее всего, это не мышь)

Comment: Например Navigation Drawer ("выдвижная панель") появляется, когда двигаем к левой границе экрана. Мне надо сделать так же, но появится не Navigation Drawer, а пока просто отловить это событие.

Comment: @kaaa прошу прощения, я не знаю тонкостей андроид студии и его апи. А вообще есть какие нибудь подписки на Drag-Drop события корневого контейнера/слоя? Может в этом направлении поискать?

Comment: Как пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/259015/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-drag-and-drop-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4 Но, это достаточно низкоуровневое решение вашей задачи, поэтому не рискну говорить что нужно развивать именно этот вариант. Скорее всего есть что то более высокоуровневое.